# Can not assign to this: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, class, scope, variable-assignment, lvalue

```
class scope{  
    //...
    scope* parent;  
    //...
public:  
    //...
    void leavescope();  
    //...
};  
void scope::leavescope(){  
    this = this->parent; // complains about this line  
}
```

I'm trying to implement scope, and am having trouble leaving a scope and getting back to the outer level scope.

Comment: The compiler is right, you can't assign `this`.  To fix this you need to describe you use case better.  Are you creating many of these `scope` objects?  It seems that way.  Normally you just let one go out of scope, which destroys it.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a *prvalue* or pure rvalue and can not be modified, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `9.3.2` *The this pointer* says:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. [...]

It is not clear why you would want to modify *this* at all.